# SQL join 3 tables and calculate total and percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a bit new to SQL and would like to do some query on these tables. the schema looks like this:

tb1:

| id | date | store_id | sold_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2000-01-01 10:00 | store1 | 30 |
| def | 2000-01-02 12:00 | store1 | 20 |
| ghi | 2000-01-01 13:00 | store2 | 40 |
| jkl | 2000-01-01 17:00 | store1 | 50 |

tb2:

| id | error_id | error_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mno | error1 | error_type_A |
| pqr | error2 | error_type_A |
| stu | error3 | error_type_B |
| vwx | error4 | error_type_B |
| yz | error5 | error_type_B |

tb3:

| tb1_id | tb2_id |
| --- | --- |
| abc | mno |
| abc | pqr |
| def | stu |
| ghi | vwx |
| jkl | yz |

I want to do a query only for date 2000-01-01 and get a table like this:

| Total_Sold | Total_Error | Error_Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 4 | 0.0333 |

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You should try build you own query and post here, another thing how did you get Total_Error and Error_Rate results?

Comment: I's seriously consider integer id's instead of those cryptic abc, jkl etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query:

```
select sum(sold) sold,
       sum(errors) errors,
       sum(errors)/sum(sold) error_rate
from (
    select max(sold_count) sold,
           count(*) errors
    from tbl1
    join junction j on tbl1.id = j.tb1_id
    join tbl2 on j.tb2_id = tbl2.id
    where tbl1.dt = '2000-01-01'
    group by tbl1.id
) a;
```

[Demo with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cbddf2/13)

CAUTION: I used sample column names, so make sure you adjust the query :)